# How to change the default time range of storage group data directory in Apache IoTDB?

Tags: directory, apache-iotdb, iotdb

I noticed that in order to avoid data expiration in Apache IoTDB, the data of each stroage group will be segmented and stored by time range. By default, the data will be stored in a different directory in units of weeks. I want to know if I can modify this default value in weeks and how can I change this?

how to deal this question,someone help please

Answer (score 0):

You can try to set the `time_partition_interval` parameter in Apache IoTDB. This parameter is the default data time partition interval of database and the unit is in milliseconds. The default value, therefore, is 604800000. You can change this value to what you need.
Remember this parameter only allows modification before starting IoTDB for the first time, so maybe you need to delete all directories and restart IoTDB again to change it.